# Is it Possible To Generate a "Diff" Between Two Strings in PostgreSQL (or in a Library/Tool)?

Tags: postgresql, diff

When one compares two strings, there's a standard "diff" format.  If I removed the letter "A" and replaced it with the letter "B", a diff of the change might look like:

```
- A
+ B
```

My question is, does PostgreSQL have any way (either built-in, or via 3rd-party code) to generate such a "diff" from two varchar or text inputs?

Comment: 1) Postgres version? 2) Where do you want to do this? In a query, stored to a table? More detail would be helpful. Add information as update to question

Comment: I'll upgrade to any version necessary to make this work :)  And as for where, the plan is to make or find a `diff` function, and then use it as part of a trigger when certain tables/columns are updated.

Comment: Per request add information as update to question, not as a comment.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such pre-built  library available. You would have to roll your own. It is possible to compare `NEW` and `OLD` in a trigger function [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). You would need to decide how to format that for your use. You could also use another PL language, say [plpythonu](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) and use an external module like [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html).

Comment: So what would be the difference between: *Good String* and *Bad String*?

Comment: I don't understand, where did "good" and "bad" strings come from?  I'm trying to get the "diff" (ie. difference) between two strings.

Comment: They are just two strings values. What would be the difference between those strings?

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/diff-command-in-linux and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81998/understanding-of-diff-output explain diff output